# use content of two variables and use it as one

Tags: javascript, html, variables

This might be a very basic question but I don't really get understand what is happening.

If I have a few `var`s in Javascript like below:

```
var cube1 = paper.rect(200, 200, 0, 0);
var cube2 = paper.rect(300, 200, 0, 0);
...
```

it goes to `cube99`.

To catch all cubes in I'm doing the following in a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cube+i.attr(fill: '#000');
    console.log(i);
}
```

but it throws me an undefined error that "cube isn't available".

Why is this happening?

Comment: here concatenation is trying to access value of var cube. therefore you are getting the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing your variables are global, then they're property of the `window` object. You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) :

```
window['cube'+i].attr(fill: '#000');
```

But a better practice would be to store all your cubes in an array :

```
var cubes = [];
cubes.push(paper.rect(200, 200, 0, 0));
...
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cubes[i].attr(fill: '#000');
    ...
}
```

Comment: could you please explain, just to understand it for me.

Comment: @supersize in your code, the computer thinks you're saying "the value of cube plus the value of i". The bracket syntax lets you use strings, which tell the computer that you want to use the *word* "cube" (not the value of cube), add the *value* of i, then interpret all of that as a variable.

Comment: @supersize every (global) variable declared with var is going to be a readonly property of the window object. so var a = "test" on the global scope can be called from anywhere as a or window["a"] . Thus var cube1 = ... can be called as cube1 or window["cube1"]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating lots of variables, you should use a single array which contains all info:

```
var cubes = [
    paper.rect(200, 200, 0, 0),  // cubes[0]
    paper.rect(300, 200, 0, 0),  // cubes[1]
    // ...
    paper.rect(300, 200, 0, 0)   // cubes[99]
];

for(var i = 0, len = cubes.length; i < len; ++i) {
    cubes[i].attr(fill: '#000');
    console.log(i);
}
```

**Note**:

```
cubes[i].attr(fill: '#000');
```

is not valid JS. Maybe you should use

```
cubes[i].setAttribute('fill', '#000');
```